# Open REST API response in pdf from browser

Tags: php, api, rest

I have issues opening PDF document from REST API response in browser.

My PHP function is as following:

```
<?php 
function printdocument(){
$documentArray = array(
     array('doc' => array('id' => '20613')),
);
#-> The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
   'userName' => 'username',
   'password' => 'password',
   'paperSize' => 'A4',
   'parcels' => $documentArray
);
$jsResponse = apiRequest(https://api.call.com/print/', $jsonData);
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
header('Content-type:application/pdf');
echo $jsResponse;
}
?>
```

And I receive error from almost all browsers:

```
Error
Failed to load PDF document.
```

Comment: Are you sure api returning pdf document and not base64 text. If base64 you should run base64_decode first. And no need to set multiple content type headers. Try this header('Content-type: ' . 'application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: ' . 'attachment; filename=filename.pdf');
echo $jsResponse;

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf");
```

This fixed the issue but now the PDF document is forced to download instead of open in preview. I prefer to load it in browser preview instead of download.

Could you please share your opinion?